# XPath search by reference

Tags: xpath

How can I search for the value of Object.name in data:One only by knowing the value of Object.name in data:Three, using XPath?

```
<data:Three abc:ID="3">
<data:Object.name>CCC</data:Object.name>
<data:Object.Container abc:resource="#2"/>
</data:Three>

<data:Two abc:ID="2">
<data:Object.name>BBB</data:Object.name>
<data:Two.Parent abc:resource="#1"/>
</data:Two>

<data:One abc:ID="1">
<data:Object.name>This is the value</data:Object.name>
</data:One>
```

I have searched manually using:

```
/abc:ABC/data:Three[data:Object.name/contains(.,'CCC')]
/abc:ABC/data:Two[@abc:ID='2']
/abc:ABC/data:One[@abc:ID='1']
/abc:ABC/data:One[@abc:ID='1']/data:Object.name
```

However, I would like *one* XPath query to search for "CCC" (first query) and then follow the abc:resource from "Three" to "One".

Is this possible?

Simplified version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Three ID="3">
        <Object.name>CCC</Object.name>
        <Object.Container resource="#2"/>
    </Three>
    <Two ID="2">
        <Object.name>BBB</Object.name>
        <Two.Parent resource="#1"/>
    </Two>
    <One ID="1">
        <Object.name>This is the value</Object.name>
    </One>
</root>

/root/Three/Object.name[contains(.,'CCC')]
/root/Two[@ID='2']
/root/One[@ID='1']
/root/One[@ID='1']/Object.name
```

Comment: I counld not get what you want , would you please add more details by adding the output you need.

Comment: Hello Muhammad! I added a simplified version below the original.

Comment: Put the output result you want from the xpath please

Comment: I would like one query to output "This is the value" based on match on "CCC"

Comment: You want something like that : .//Two[@ID=translate(string(.//Three[Object.name[contains(.,'CCC')]]/Object.Container/@resource) ,'#', '')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this what you want : this get the One's element related to the Three's element.
Here are how to get it

firstly you want to get the reference of **Three** element

```
//Three[Object.name[contains(.,'CCC')]]/Object.Container/@resource
```

This will get

```
#2
```

We will eliminate the # by replacing it

```
translate(//Three[Object.name[contains(.,'CCC')]]/Object.Container/@resource ,'#', '')
```

the output will be

```
2
```

We will do the same for **Two** element and **One** element.

And the final XPath will be

```
.//One[@ID=translate(//Two[@ID=translate(//Three[Object.name[contains(.,'CCC')]]/Object.Container/@resource ,'#', '')]/Two.Parent/@resource ,'#', '')]/Object.name/text()
```

which resulting

```
This is the value
```

I hope this could help.